# VBA: Getting the 'Complile Error - Invalid Use of Property'

Tags: excel, xml, vba

```
Private Sub Clear_Click()

    transactiondate.Value = ""

    itemcode.Value = ""

    description.Value = ""

    Partno.Value = ""

    transactiontype.Value = ""

    qtty2.Value = ""

    uom.Value = ""

    Location.Value = ""

    balance.Value ""

End Sub
```

How do I get my command button to **clear the screen** instead of getting the *'Complile Error - Invalid Use of Property'*

Comment: Please ask an question with more details

Answer (score 0):

The .value is not always equal to "". Integer must be equal to 0.

```
String.value = ""
Integer.value = 0
Double.value = 0
```